# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models. Unable to import models into folder

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating a project in django called social_monitoring and I'm getting the error within the app 'fb_scraping'.

I'm trying to import models from the models folder that I have created into a python file in another folder in the same directory. But, it keeps giving me this error

```
from models.scrapingmodels import Scrapedposts, Postcomments
```

Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

The structure of the project:

> social_monitoring/
> --└── fb_scraping/
> -----├── models/
> -----│ -----├──__init__.py
> -----│ -----└──scrapingmodels.py (where I'm importing from)
> -----└── scripts/
> -----------└──fbscrape.py (where I'm importing to)

scrapingmodels.py contains 2 class: Scrapedposts and Postcomments
In the **init**.py file in models folder, I've added:

```
from .scrapingmodels import Scrapedposts as _Scrapedposts
from .scrapingmodels import Postcomments as _Postcomments
```

In fbscrape.py, I have tried to import in several ways:

```
from fb_scraping.models.scrapingmodels import Postcomments, Scrapedposts
```

and i get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fb_scraping'

What do you suggest I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try adding an empty `__init__.py` inside your `fb_scraping` folder?

Comment: Yes, I just added it, but made no difference.

Comment: please try: from .models import _Scrapedposts, _Postcomments

Comment: On adding the above line i get the error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package